# how to add click listener to row of a-table in antd vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, antd

This is the code snippet for the table which I am trying to render, have imported `a-table` from *`antd`*. Currently, we can add an extra `td` to achieve click functionality to route to details page from this listing page

```
<a-table
    :columns="companiesColumns"
    :dataSource="getDisplayData"
    class="companies-table"
    :pagination="false"
    rowKey="id"
    >
    <span slot="nse_symbol" slot-scope="nse_symbol" class="nse-symbol">
        <span>{{ nse_symbol || '-' }}</span>
    </span>
</a-table>
```

Comment: Please add your reproducible code snippet

Answer (score 2):

Antd Vue does include a property `customRow` which lets you set props per row.

Example usage (please note: antdvue is using a vue jsx syntax here)

```
<Table
  customRow={(record) => {
    return {
      props: {
        xxx...
      },
      on: {
        click: (event) => {},       // click row
        dblclick: (event) => {}, // double click row
        contextmenu: (event) => {}  // right button click row
        mouseenter: (event) => {}   // mouse enter row
        mouseleave: (event) => {}   // mouse leave row
      },
    };
  )}
  customHeaderRow={(column) => {
    return {
      on: {
        click: () => {},        // click header row
      },
    };
  )}
/>
```

More details here : https://www.antdv.com/components/table/#customRow-usage

#### Update

As OP pointed out, this example from the docs requires an additional plugin for it to work. The plugin can be found here : https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx

Comment: actually I guess this is more of JSX for which I have to add a new jsx library to support in vue ???

Comment: Nah this is plain vue ( vue single file template ) - I took it straight from the "Ant Design Vue" documentation. I'll update my answer with an example .

Comment: @shubh You are absolutely correct - the example in the antd vue docs for customRow requires an additional plugin ! Wonder how I missed that. I am pretty sure there is a "native" vue way of doing this as well. I'll update my answer once I have a solution.

Comment: Here is how to [use customRow without jsx](https://github.com/vueComponent/ant-design-vue/issues/834#issuecomment-627138202)

Answer (score 2):

**Without using the jsx plugin:**

Modified code from Matt Sanders

```
<a-table :dataSource="dataSource" :columns="columns" rowKey="id" :customRow="customRow">

const customRow = (record) => {
 return {
  onClick: (event) => {console.log('click row', record);}
 };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vue 3

AntDesign v3.0.0-beta.9

This is the only way that worked for me:

```
#template

<template>
  <a-table 
    :columns='columns'
    :data-source='data'
    @change='onChange'
    :customRow="customRow"
    :row-selection='rowSelection'
    :pagination="pagination"
  />
</template>

#methods

methods: {
 customRow(record: TableDataType) {
      return {
          onClick: (event: PointerEvent) => console.log('record', record, 'event', event)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No need to use jsx plugin here, and I found Roman's snippet not working for me, but [this](https://github.com/vueComponent/ant-design-vue/issues/834#issuecomment-627138202) worked:

```
<a-table :customRow="customRow"></a-table>

function customRow(record) {
      return {
        on: {
          click: event => {
            console.log(event, record);
          }
        }
      };
    }
```